# Does this almost-group uniquely define a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, quasigroups

Consider a quasigroup $(S,+)$ such that for every $a,b,c,d\in S$, $$(a+(b+c))+d=a+(b+(c+d)).$$

This is *almost* a group, but not quite. For instance, $(\mathbb Z,-)$ satisfies those axioms.

You can easily prove that for any element $x$, the operation $a+_xb:=a+(x+b)$ yields a group.

But I wonder: for any given $(S,+)$ and any pair $x,y \in S$, are $(S,+_x)$ and $(S,+_y)$ neccessarily isomorphic?

Comment: In fact, $(G,-)$ satisfies these axioms for $G$ any abelian group, where $-$ is interpreted as $(a,b)\mapsto (a+(-b)$.

Comment: I don't know if this is useful, but I've just noticed that $a+_x (b +_y c) = (a +_x b) +_y c$ holds

Comment: If $(S,-)$ is obtained from an abelian group $(G,+)$ by the above procedure, then I claim that the group $(S,+_x)$ is isomorphic to $G=(S,+_0)$. I believe the function $a\mapsto a+x$ is a homomorphism of groups.

Comment: Well, in this specific case it's obvious. But I believe you can have quasigroups that still satisfy this and aren't in this form.

Comment: Sorry, I hope you take no offence -- it's just that the case of $(S,-)$ is fairly well-known. Or at least I thought so.

Comment: It might be known to quasigroup theorists. But as a group theorist I've never seen this before, and you tagged it group theory. If the structure of these objects has been studied before, why not mention it in the question? You know, like MSE guidelines suggest you do?

Comment: To be fair, I'm not much of anything theorist, just a student. I don't know if this specific result appears in any literature, it just seemed fairly obvious to me. But you're right, I should have said so in the question, my bad. I'm terribly sorry four your waiste of time (if you do indeed treat it as such).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A colleague of mine has been able to prove that this is, indeed, the case. His proof had some redundant steps, below is a polished version.

Theorem: If a quasigroup $(S,+)$ satisfies the axiom $(*)$:

$$ (a+(b+c))+d=a+(b+(c+d))$$

Then for any $x \in S$, operation $a+_xb:=a+(x+b)$ forms a group. Furthermore, any two such groups $(S,+_x)$,$(S,+_y)$ for given $(S,+)$ are isomorphic.

Lemma 1: $(S,+)$ has right-identity.

Proof: $(S,+)$ is a quasigroup, for any $c$ there exists $d$ such that $c+d=c$. Therefore:

$$(a+(b+c))+d=a+(b+c)$$

Let $x:=(a+(b+c))$. Since we've put no constraints on $a,b,c$, this can be any element of $S$. We have:

$$x+d=x$$

So $d$ is the right-identity. From this point on the right-identity will be denoted as $0$.

Corollary: From the existence of right-identity and the properties of a quasigroup, it trivially follows that any operation $+_x$ has a right-identity and right-invertability.

Lemma 2: $+_x$ is asociative.

Proof:

$(a+_xb)+_xc\overset{def}{=}(a+(x+b))+(x+c)\overset{(*)}{=} a+(x+(b+(x+c)))\overset{def}{=}a+_x(b+_xc)$

This establishes that $(S,+_x)$ indeed forms a group.

Lemma 3: $$0+(0+a)=a$$

Proof: $$x+a=(x+(0+0))+a\overset{(*)}{=}x+(0+(0+a))$$

Since $(S,+)$ is a quasigroup, the lemma follows.

Lemma 4: $$(x+y)+(0+z)=x+(y+z)$$

Proof:

$$(x+y)+(0+z)=(x+(y+0))+(0+z)\overset{(*)}{=}x+(y+(0+(0+z)))\overset{\text{L3}}{=}x+(y+z)$$

Now, we have sufficient tools to prove that $f(x)=k+x$ is a homomorphism from $(S,+_k)$ to $(S,+_0)$ for any $k \in S$

$$f(x)+_0f(y)\overset{def}{=}(k+x)+(0+(k+y))\overset{(*)}{=}((k+x)+(0+k))+y\overset{\text{L4}}{=}(k+(x+k))+y\overset{(*)}{=}\cdots$$

$$\cdots \overset{(*)}{=} k+(x+(k+y))\overset{def}{=}f(x+_ky)$$

This establishes homomorphism. Now, since $(S,+)$ is a quasigroup, $f(x)$ a bijection and therefore isomorphism. Since for any two $x,y \in S$, $(S,+_x)$ and $(S,+_y)$ are isomorphic with $(S,+_0)$ and isomorphism is obviously transitive, this proves the theorem.

Corollary: this theorem led to a surprizing rezult. All quasigroups $(S,+)$ satisfying the axiom $(*)$ can be represented as: $x+y=x \star f(y)$, where $(S,\star)$ is a group, and where $f(x)$ is an automorphism of said group such that $f(f(x))=x$. Furthermore, any operation $x \star f(y)$ forms a quasigroup satisfying the axiom $(*)$. The proof isn't hard, but it's beyond the scope of the original question, so I'll omit it.